# Atualizar JLabel com contagem regresiva

Tags: java

Tenho um `For` que faz uma contagem regressiva, porem quando vou passar o valor para o `Label` ele só pega o ultimo valor do laço.

Esse é meu método:

```
public static void contagemRegressiva(){

        System.out.println("Start");
        int i=0;
        for( i=10;i>=0;i--){
            //label
           numero[0].setText(""+i);
        }

    }
```

O resultado da `Label` vai pra 0 direto.

Answer (score 3):

Isto ocorre provavelmente porque o código é executado tão rapidamente que você só consegue ver o último valor.

O ideal seria definir um Timer para rodar a cada 1 segundo e então atualizar o label.

Você pode ver como usar a classe `Timer` [nesta minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5890/227). Basta adicionar um comando para atualizar o label onde os segundos são decrementados.

Answer (score 1):

Como o @utluiz disse isso é porque o teu código executa rapidamente, o valor está a mudar mas não consegues visualizar essa troca por ser tão rápida...

Insere esta linha de código:

```
Thread.sleep(1000); //faz com que o teu programa adormeça durante 1 segundo
```

atenção: que deves de tratar a exceção na possibilidade de ser lançada:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // handle the exception...        
    // For example consider calling Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); here.
}
```

Comment: Só precisa se atentar para o uso de 'sleep' consentido de que ele bloqueia a thread, então se não houver outra thread o programa para de responder. Dependendo da velocidade de atualização da GUI o programa pode ainda não exibir as atualizações, pois com a pausa ele também não tem tempo para renderizar o componente. Entretanto é possível contornar isso forçando a renderização do componente manualmente.